# Install PHP Version in Mac 32 Bit

Tags: php, macos

I have installed on my computer version of PHP 5.3.4 with OS 10.6.8.

I wanted to create a project with Symfony, but returns an error saying:

**Symfony requires PHP >= 5.3.9, your PHP version (5.3.4).**

I tried to download new versions of PHP from http://php-osx.liip.ch 
But I could not install new versions, even version 5.4:

**ERROR! 32 BIT NOT SUPPORTED!
No 64bit capable system found ..**

I understand that this is due to my computer processor.

But there is a way to install than the 5.3 versions, 32 bits having?

I have installed MAMP 2.2 and runs on version 5.5.3 of PHP

No way to do that is the version of my computer?

Thanks!

Comment: It's going to be very hard to install an unsupported PHP version on an unsupported OS X version, if you're not comfortable with compiling yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the documentation from the PHP official site.

[PHP Installation on Mac OS](http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.php)